# how to make javascript dynamic in android(add value to variable array)

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I am using following code in assets folder and loading the code .How to make the code value dynamic ?

Specifically how to add values to  variable array from server instead of adding value statically from html file .['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4]

Please guide me, Really appreciate any help.Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**mainActivity:**

```
myWebView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use html tags to prase some data dynamically. Please see following example as a reference:

1. In your HTML file:

   var locations = %locations_list%;
2. In your mainActivity:

   ```
   private static final String HTML_FILE = "your_html_file.html";
   private static final String HTML_FILE_DESTINATION = "file:///android_asset/your_html_file.html";
   private static final String MIME_TYPE = "text/html";
   private static final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";

       private void setWebViewConfiguration(){       

       webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
       webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
       webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);

       /** Set tokens. */

       String content = readTextFromHTML(getActivity(), HTML_FILE)
               .replaceAll( %locations_list%, "[['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5]]");

       /** Load data. */

       webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(
               HTML_FILE_DESTINATION, content,
               MIME_TYPE, ENCODING, null);
                }

       public static String readTextFromHTML(Context context, String file) {
       InputStream is;
       try {
           is = context.getAssets().open(file);
           int size = is.available();
           byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
           is.read(buffer);
           is.close();
           return new String(buffer);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           return "";
       }
           }
   ```